# How to install and verify asynchronous Google Analytics tracking code?

Tags: google-analytics

In my property's *Tracking Code* section I see this message:

> #### Status: Tracking Not Installed Last checked: Oct ...
>
> The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's home
>   page. For Analytics to function, you or your web administrator must
>   add the code to each page of your website.

The tracking code shown to be copy/pasted is this:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXx', 'example.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

There's a learn more button and when I click it it takes me to [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en&utm_id=ad) which shows the asynchronous code, which is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Is this the current/latest version of the GA code? Why is the dashboard (i.e. the *Tracking Code* section) is not showing this by default? Is there a way to customize the Google Analytics to show this code in the *Tracking Code* section, prepared for my property (website)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing first is the latest version of Google Analytics known as Universal Analytics. As per Google recommendation , use that for all your new analytics properties. This is identified by the `analytics.js` library in the tracking code

The second one is an earlier version of Google Analytics based on `ga.js` library.

Use the first version of tracking code given by GA and follow this [tutorial based on analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) to debug your code.